# heroku db:push Taps Load Error:

Tags: postgresql, heroku, rubygems, taps

Does anyone facing this problem according to push data to heroku postgres using `heroku db:push`

here's error

```
D:\workspace\gitrepo\xxx> heroku db:push

 !    Taps Load Error: no such file to load -- taps/operation
 !    You may need to install or update the taps gem to use db commands.
 !    On most systems this will be:
 !
 !    sudo gem install taps
```

after this error occured I've try to use add a Database_url somethings like this

```
D:\workspace\gitrepo\xxx> heroku db:push postgres://postgres:mypassword@localhost:5432
```

It's showing the same error

So I've try to re-install new taps using command

```
sudo heroku install taps
```

showing error

```
'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

#### My workstation information

- OS: Window 7
- Heroku Toolbelt lastetst version download on 2 July 2012
- Gems

  ```
  D:\workspace\gitrepo\xxx> gem list

  *** LOCAL GEMS ***

  foreman (0.47.0, 0.45.0)
  mime-types (1.18)
  minitest (1.6.0)
  rack (1.4.1)
  rake (0.8.7)
  rdoc (2.5.8)
  rest-client (1.6.7)
  sequel (3.20.0)
  sinatra (1.0)
  taps (0.3.24)
  thor (0.15.0)
  ```

Answer (score 1):

sudo is a linux command.  It seems from your questions, you are using Windows 7.  So, that is not going to work for you.

Comment: Just a note here.  The equivalent on Windows is runas but you may need special rights to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have ruby installed, then:

Open the command shell `(‘Start’ >> ‘Run’ >> ‘cmd’)`, and navigate to the ruby `bin` directory. normally this will be `C:\ruby` and run `gem install taps –include-dependencies`; this should install the gem.